# My flutter app freezes on white screen before opening

Tags: flutter

I've made an app with flutter an it freezes on startup on but on the device I used to debug it with vs code it runs perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Add this line `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` to your `main()` function

Comment: it stil doesn't work. It opens on a white screen then it gets to a gray and it freezes there